# Detect return from system screen

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

At some point my App needs to show at list of available networks, thats no problem:

```
private void ShowConnectionSettings()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ShowConnectionSettings()");

    //Use the ConnectionSettingsTask to bring up the connection settings
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettingsTask();

    // We are using the Connection Settings page for AirplaneMode.
    connectionSettings.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
    connectionSettings.Show();
}
```

Bu how do I detect when the user have removed that screen again? I need a `OnReturnFromSystemScreen` event or something like that.

I've done some tests:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   txtHeader.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    txtHeader.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtHeader.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    }
```

But thats not enough. So any idears would be helpfull.

Comment: Keep a view_count flag in IsolatedStorage and increase it by one on every protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the most obvious the Activated and Deactivated events

```
// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   //do stuff
}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

when my system screen is shown Deactivated is called and when I return Activated is called.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an event for returning from system screen, the closest you can do is probably use [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto(v=vs.95).aspx) and check [NavigationEventArgs.NavigationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.navigationmode(v=vs.95).aspx) for the value `Back` which will indicate if you navigated back to the page using back navigation. And then also check [IsNavigationInitiator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.isnavigationinitiator(v=vs.95).aspx) which indicates if the Navigation started in the app. Like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back && e.IsNavigationInitiator == false)
    {
        txtHeader.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationmode(v=vs.95).aspx for all values of NavigationMode.

Answer (score 0):

The results from your tests are not clear to me. If you are having trouble getting the event raised on your own code:

"Typically the event is marked handled by the class handler, and the GotFocus event is not raised for handling by any user code handlers on that control."

You need to explicitly override the OnGotFocus eventhandler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.gotfocus.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.ongotfocus.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answeres but none of them did the trick for me since I do not get ant events.

I've triede to put code in  Application_Activated and i've tried to override OnGotFocus:

        protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
            txtHeader.Text = "BACK: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        } 
But so far no luck